# html newsletter for outlook 2007/10

Tags: html, email, outlook

i had been trying to get the html newsletter on an id configured using outlook 2007/10, but the issue is that i am unable to get the background image, it just appears blank there. is there any way to get the background image there?? Or is there no  way i can get the image ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Full Width Backgrounds on Outlook '07/'10/'13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23280715/full-width-backgrounds-on-outlook-07-10-13)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background-images are not allowed for outlook 2007. You can use regular images though...
I think that is the reason why you are unable to retrieve the background-image. It won't get trough.

Check this detailed cheetsheet for css and html support at different email-platforms:

[Campaign Monitor Email Support Cheatsheet](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)

Comment: Ehh... plain no...Blame microsoft.